# convert character date (eg, November 17, 2021) to date format(yyyy-mm-dd) in R

Tags: r, date

I have character date format, November 17, 2021, and how can I convert it into the date format, 2021-11-17 in R? I have tried as.Date() but it returns an error. Thanks so much for your help.

```
x <- "November 17, 2021"
as.Date(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `lubridate` library, you can do:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(lubridate)
x <- "November 17, 2021"
mdy(x)
```

- Output

```r
# "2021-11-17"
```

Comment: Thanks so much and it helps me a lot.